# How do I keep Java for loops from breaking when charAt(i) = ' '?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char, break

I have a program which is supposed to check the number of #s and @s in a string.  My code works correctly, but the for loop breaks when it reaches a space in the string for no apparent reason.  I've looked extensively online, but I can't find anything in documentation or in other help forums about a problem like this.
The issue is not the code giving an error, it just exits the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if(tweet.charAt(i) == '@' && tweet.charAt(i+1) != ' '){
        attribution++;
    }
    else if(tweet.charAt(i) == '#' && tweet.charAt(i+1) != ' '){
        hashtag++;
    }
}
```

Here are some examples of the code running:

```
> run Main
Please enter a tweet:
#hashtag@attribution#hashtag
Length Correct
Number of Hashtags: 2
Number of Attributions: 1
Number of Links: 0
> 

> run Main
Please enter a tweet:
#hashtag @attribution #hashtag
Length Correct
Number of Hashtags: 1
Number of Attributions: 0
Number of Links: 0
>
```

Here is the entire program:

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.lang.Math;

class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int hashtag = 0;
    int attribution = 0;
    int link = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter a tweet:");
    String tweet = scan.next();
    int length = tweet.length();
    if(length > 140){
      int excess = length - 140;
      System.out.println("Excess Characters: " + excess);
    }
    else if(length-1 <= 140){
          for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if(tweet.charAt(i) == '@' && tweet.charAt(i+1) != ' '){
        attribution++;
    }
    else if(tweet.charAt(i) == '#' && tweet.charAt(i+1) != ' '){
        hashtag++;
    }
}
      System.out.println("Length Correct\nNumber of Hashtags: " + hashtag + "\nNumber of   Attributions: " + attribution + "\nNumber of Links: " + link);
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("What the bloody hell have you done?");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is `length` computed?

Comment: print the string and show us its content 
   System.out.println("-" + tweet + "-");

Comment: Should be **; i < (length - 1);**, because **.charAt(i+1)** hits over boundary.

Comment: Your code doesn't break on a space when I run it.  What is your source string, and which character does it break on?

Comment: Do you mean "breaks when it reaches a space" (i.e. exits the loop when it reaches a space) or do you mean "throws an exception when I put in the stuff about spaces"? because there is nothing in your quoted code that could possibly be issuing a `break`.

Comment: @Margus The OP probably isn't running into that particular condition, since it will only arise if the string ends with a '@' or '#' (which is unlikely in a tweet).  It sounds like something screwy is happening earlier in the parsing.

Comment: int length = tweet.length();

Comment: The code exits the for loop when it reaches a space in the string

Comment: @user2336634 No it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe you.  Perhaps you are running a different version of the code than the one you have described, or perhaps the problem is different than you say, but that loop does not exit in any way before examining `length` characters unless `tweet` is `null` or there are fewer than `length` characters in it.

Comment: @user2336634 Step through your code in a debugger and note *precisely* where the loop abnormally breaks.  Then come back here and edit your question to include the source string you are parsing, and the *exact* internal state of the program when it does so.

Comment: @khelwood yes it does, I will add some examples of the program running on Monday when I'm back on the computer the program is on.

Comment: >"I am using the Dr. Java IDE. I've never used a debugger with Java and I don't have access to one." — this is suspicious, looks like trolling. What can prevent you from downloading Eclipse or IDEA? They are free to use and have integrated debuggers.

Comment: @SargeBorsch I'm on my school's computers, I don't have permission to install software.

Comment: @user2336634 you can try this at home

Comment: @SargeBorsch I don't have the program at home

Comment: @user2336634 you can debug these lines alone, they seem to be self-sufficient and you already dumped them to this site. Write down the link to your question, copy and paste code… is it hard?

Comment: @SargeBorsch my home computer is broken right now, my only internet connected device is a Nexus tablet

Comment: @user2336634 https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+on+nexus+tablet

Comment: @SargeBorsch I've looked into that before, and i would love to dual boot Ubuntu and Android on my Nexus, unfortunately i need a computer to do that.

Comment: @user2336634 try solving this problem, you will need it later anyway

Comment: So, how did it go? Did you solve the problem? If yes, choose an answer and accept it, or write your own answer if you solved it in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will break when the `@` or `#` character is at the end of the string, because you check `charAt(i+1)` without ensuring that `i+1` is less than `length`.

There is a simpler way of finding out the number of hash tags and `@`s in the string - all you need to do is replacing the desired characters with empty strings, and comparing the length, like this:

```
String text = "...";
int numHashTags = text.length() - text.replaceAll("#(?!\\s)", "").length();
int numAttr = text.length() - text.replaceAll("@(?!\\s)", "").length();
```

Note the `(?!\\s)` of regular expressions. These [*negative lookaheads*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) prevent regex from matching the symbol when it is followed by a space.

Comment: I tried using your regular expressions, but they still have the same problem as my code; they won't count #s or @s after a space. I'm starting to wonder if there's something wrong with the compiler I'm using.

Comment: @user2336634 I cannot tell for sure, but this certainly works on ideone ([demo](http://ideone.com/g2IWlI)).

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't do bounds checking.
When you access `i + 1` element, and `i` is equal to `length - 1`, you access by invalid index (`length`), hence the error.
(I'm assuming that `length` is the length of the string)

Also, this task can be done in 1 line of code by using regular expressions! Try doing this instead of writing loops. (Unless you already know that this is performance bottleneck and you are trying to optimize)

Comment: Although this is true, it doesn't answer the question.  The OP says his loop "breaks" (exits prematurely), and that it does it when it reaches a *space*.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < tweet.length() - 1 ; i ++){
   if (tweet.charAt(i+1) != ' '){
    if(tweet.charAt(i) == '@'{
        attribution++;
   }
   else if(tweet.charAt(i) == '#' ){
      hashtag++;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Although this code does solve the out-of-bounds indexing issue, it doesn't answer the question (see clarifications presented in the comments).  In fairness, though, the question as clarified is inconsistent.

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php and ended with this sample.

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String test = "Hello #Wor@l@d";
    int hasHashTag = 0;
    int hasAt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        if (test.charAt(i) == '#') hasHashTag++;
        if (test.charAt(i) == '@') hasAt++;
    }
    System.out.println(hasHashTag);
    System.out.println(hasAt);
 }
```

}

Comment: How is this an answer?  Instead of helping the OP get his code working, you've removed functionality from it (obviously he didn't want to count # and @ that were followed by space characters, and you took that test out).

Comment: Actually, hi first sentence states "I have a program which is supposed to check the number of #s and @s in a string". There's not any constraint about spaces after it, and besides the fact that it was present in his code, it was not clear it should be coded that way. It wasn't "obvious" it should be done this way.

Comment: Fair point, but since this appears to be connected with Twitter strings it seems more likely that the `' '` test is intentional and that he just didn't state his problem clearly.